# How can I disable Javascript error messages within browser consoles?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, vimeo, froogaloop

I am using the old `Froogaloop2 Vimeo library` and I know that this library is deprecated, but I have multiple embeds in a website and it was the only way I could get it to run.

There are console errors...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined
>       at l (froogaloop2.min.js:1)
>   30froogaloop2.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>       at l (froogaloop2.min.js:1)

I've tried to disable `console.log` but this unfortunately doesn't fall under that output.

`console.log = function() {}`

I simply want to avoid the outputs above.

Comment: this is not the console.log function that show this message , it seem ou have a error message . like **new Error([message[, nomFichier[, numeroLigne]]])**

Comment: indeed, i know, wondering how to disable error messages completely

Comment: Short of writing your own browser, that doesn't have a console/error reporting, then forcing the entire world to use it ... I *think* you're gonna be out of luck ;)

Comment: The normal user does not have the console open, so its already "ignored".

Comment: i read that you can wrap the whole code in a try { } catch {} ... and then maybe the error would be eliminated?

Comment: Try this : **Error = function(){...}**

Comment: why would you want to do this, why not fix the issues that are causing the errors? they are there for a reason!

Comment: *"wrap the whole code in a try {} catch {}"* ... depressingly, that would actually sort of work - you're essentially catching all errors but not handling them. You'd certainly avoid that `Uncaught TypeError` as you'd be catching it...

Comment: There's a dropdown in the developer console (Chrome) that says: **Custom levels**. If you open it you can set what you want to see (you can uncheck **Errors**).

Comment: Stop trying to hide your errors, what kind of solution is that? Use the unminified JS and then check the error at line X

Comment: this is because the only way to embed multiple vimeo videos in a slider is to use OLD FROOGALOOP2...

Answer (score 1):

or disable all console logs ;)

```
 for (let func in console) {
      console[func] = function () {};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need disable "console.log()" try this.

```js
console.log("Hello World."); // Output : "Hello World."

console.log = function (param) {return;}

console.log("Hello World."); // Output : nothing.
```